# What does Civilization Revolution mean by Have 3 Population in 3 Cities?

Tags: civilization-revolution-2

I play Civilization Revolution 2 on my iPad. I have encountered the bonus goal option "Have 3 population in 3 cities" a few times, but I've never been able to achieve it. At least, I think I've had 3 population in 3 cities many times, but the game doesn't count it.

[image: screenshot showing the goal of Have 3 Population in 3 Cities, but with 0/3 acknowledged]
[image: screenshot showing Paris with 3 population]
[image: screenshot showing Besancon with 3 population]
[image: screenshot showing Lyons with 3 population]

What are the actual requirements for meeting this goal? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, I had to increase the number of workers in the city (not working outside the city) to 3 in 4 cities.[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying that you actually need 3 workers in the city?

Comment: I'll try this. Weird that you should need to do it in _four_ cities.